# RhinoMocks - stubbed method only called once

Tags: rhino-mocks

Here's some test code:

```csharp
var searchCommand = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISearchCommand>();
activityCreatedDateQuery = new ActivityCreatedDateQuery(searchCommand, maxRows);
searchCommand.Stub(x => x.GetResults(activityCreatedDateQuery))
                .Return(GetCreatedDateQueryMockData()));
```

Here's the thing...when I initially call `activityCreatedDateQuery.ExecuteQuery()` which internally calls `searchCommand.GetResults(this)`, `GetCreatedDateQueryMockData()` is called as expected.

The second time I call this in the thread, `GetCreatedDateQueryMockData()` is not called, instead the previous call's result is (resulting in an IDataReader closed exception).

This is obviously behaviour by design, so how do I make sure the delegate is always called...i've explored Stub.Repeat.WhenCalled.CallBack etc with no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "Return" doesn't take a delegate, it just takes an object.  The GetCreatedDataQueryMockData() method call is executed at the time your Stub is set and the value is saved inside the framework as the return value.

What you need is a true delegate to be called every time the stub is called.  Someone else asked about this on Stackoverflow recently and I [created a little extension method](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2011/02/02/using-lambdas-for-return-values-in-rhino-mocks.aspx) to do this.

Comment: is the right answer...just as I'd finished refactoring - that's OK as I understand the recommended best practice is that each test method should get its own stubs (not a recycled copy) - so now this is setup in a method with [SetUp] and not [TestFixtureSetUp] - that said I'm better off knowing the answer for the future. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

```csharp
searchCommand.Stub(x => x.GetResults(activityCreatedDateQuery))
            .Return(null).WhenCalled(i => i.ReturnValue = GetCreatedDateQueryMockData()));
```

worked in my case. It works because "WhenCalled()" unlike "Return()" uses delegates.

When using "WhenCalled()" do not forget to put a dummy value in "Return()".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
searchCommand.Stub(x => x.GetResults(activityCreatedDateQuery))
            .Return(GetCreatedDateQueryMockData())).Repeat.Any();
```

Comment: Are you sure GetCreatedDateQueryMockData() isn't called again - have you debugged it?  Could be that method is returning the same data reader or something.

Comment: What if you change it for something simple like `searchCommand.Stub(x => x.GetResults(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return("Hello")).Repeat.Any();`, do you get the same issue?